# where can I find the list of boost component that I can use in cmake?

Tags: c++, boost

I have a cmake file that adds boost like this:

```
if(ADD_BOOST)
#add boost library
  set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME ON)
  file(TO_CMAKE_PATH $ENV{BOOST_ROOT} BOOST_ROOT)
  if (MSVC)
    set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR ${BOOST_ROOT}/lib64-msvc-12.0)
  else (MSVC)
    set(BOOST_LIBRARY_DIR $ENV{BOOST_ROOT})
  endif (MSVC)
  find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem system program-options thread REQUIRED)
endif (ADD_BOOST)
```

I have this line:

```
 find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem system program-options thread REQUIRED)
```

I want to use program-option libabray from boost. what name should I add to the above list?

where can I find the list of boost library that I can use in above mentioned line in cmake?

Comment: [From the documentation :](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html#boost-cmake) "Boost libraries by their canonical name `date_time` for `libboost_date_time`", so I guess `program_options` ?

Comment: After looking at the FindBoost.cmake file i think Leiaz is right. If you want to understand how CMake finds libraries on your computer checkout the find-script modules. In windows you can find them in: 

C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\share\cmake-2.8\Modules\

and there the file: 'FindBoost.cmake'

Answer (score 12):

Create a dummy `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(dummy)

set(Boost_DEBUG ON)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS ALL)
```

Then check the output of `cmake .`:

```
[...]
-- BoostConfig: discovered components: atomic;chrono;container;context;coroutine;date_time;exception;fiber;filesystem;graph;graph_parallel;headers;iostreams;locale;log;log_setup;math_c99;math_c99f;math_c99l;math_tr1;math_tr1f;math_tr1l;mpi;mpi_python;nowide;numpy;prg_exec_monitor;program_options;python;random;regex;serialization;stacktrace_addr2line;stacktrace_backtrace;stacktrace_basic;stacktrace_noop;system;test_exec_monitor;thread;timer;type_erasure;unit_test_framework;wave;wserialization
[...]
-- BoostConfig: Boost_ALL_TARGETS: Boost::headers;Boost::atomic;Boost::chrono;Boost::container;Boost::context;Boost::coroutine;Boost::date_time;Boost::exception;Boost::fiber;Boost::filesystem;Boost::graph;Boost::graph_parallel;Boost::iostreams;Boost::locale;Boost::log;Boost::log_setup;Boost::math_c99;Boost::math_c99f;Boost::math_c99l;Boost::math_tr1;Boost::math_tr1f;Boost::math_tr1l;Boost::mpi;Boost::mpi_python;Boost::nowide;Boost::numpy;Boost::prg_exec_monitor;Boost::program_options;Boost::python;Boost::random;Boost::regex;Boost::serialization;Boost::stacktrace_addr2line;Boost::stacktrace_backtrace;Boost::stacktrace_basic;Boost::stacktrace_noop;Boost::system;Boost::test_exec_monitor;Boost::thread;Boost::timer;Boost::type_erasure;Boost::unit_test_framework;Boost::wave;Boost::wserialization
[...]
```

Note that this can list components only if they are installed on your system. I got the above output after installing libboost 1.74 development files on Debian 11 (e.g. `apt install libboost-all-dev=1.74.0.3`).

Here is a prettified version of above output for future reference:

```
-- BoostConfig: discovered components:
atomic
chrono
container
context
coroutine
date_time
exception
fiber
filesystem
graph
graph_parallel
headers
iostreams
locale
log
log_setup
math_c99
math_c99f
math_c99l
math_tr1
math_tr1f
math_tr1l
mpi
mpi_python
nowide
numpy
prg_exec_monitor
program_options
python
random
regex
serialization
stacktrace_addr2line
stacktrace_backtrace
stacktrace_basic
stacktrace_noop
system
test_exec_monitor
thread
timer
type_erasure
unit_test_framework
wave
wserialization
```

```
-- BoostConfig: Boost_ALL_TARGETS:
Boost::headers
Boost::atomic
Boost::chrono
Boost::container
Boost::context
Boost::coroutine
Boost::date_time
Boost::exception
Boost::fiber
Boost::filesystem
Boost::graph
Boost::graph_parallel
Boost::iostreams
Boost::locale
Boost::log
Boost::log_setup
Boost::math_c99
Boost::math_c99f
Boost::math_c99l
Boost::math_tr1
Boost::math_tr1f
Boost::math_tr1l
Boost::mpi
Boost::mpi_python
Boost::nowide
Boost::numpy
Boost::prg_exec_monitor
Boost::program_options
Boost::python
Boost::random
Boost::regex
Boost::serialization
Boost::stacktrace_addr2line
Boost::stacktrace_backtrace
Boost::stacktrace_basic
Boost::stacktrace_noop
Boost::system
Boost::test_exec_monitor
Boost::thread
Boost::timer
Boost::type_erasure
Boost::unit_test_framework
Boost::wave
Boost::wserialization
```

Comment: As of CMake 3.10, `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS ALL)` doesn't seem to work. I saw the error message `Could not find the following Boost libraries: boost_all.`

Comment: @Ryoji It [appears](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blame/c5ae200d94333600117fc93e50c66bdd50994bbc/Modules/FindBoost.cmake#L610-L611) `ALL` is a meta component introduced by Boost 1.73

Comment: does not work with cmake 3.22 also

Answer (score 0):

On an Ubuntu system, for example, run:

```
aptitude show libboost-all-dev
```

Take a look at its "Depends" output. It lists the names of all boost components.

Comment: This lists all boost components, but not the components you can use inside your cmake file.

Comment: Are you implying that there is a component in the output of the above command that **cannot** be used within the cmake file? If the component is installed, then OP **can** use it.

Answer (score -1):

> I want to use program-option libabray from boost. what name should I add to the above list?

**Can you please clarify what you mean?**
You have already added `program-options` to the line:
`find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem system program-options thread REQUIRED)`

So you don't need to add anything else to the list of components in this line.

> where can I find the list of boost library that I can use in above mentioned line in cmake?

**Can you please clarify what you mean?**

The list of libraries is available on https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/ .

Or check the sub-directories in `include/boost` or `include/boost_1_68/boost` directory, respectively, under your `$BOOST_ROOT` folder.
In fact the sub-directory names can be used as component names for the `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS...)` command. (Exception: Boost numpy, which is included in Boost python. [See here.](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html))

But if you wanted to know how to get the list of found boost components in CMake:

1. You can try the undocumented `_Boost_IMPORTED_TARGETS` variable (which is a [CMake list](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html)).
2. Or you can try to hack with the documented [Boost_LIBRARIES variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/module/FindBoost.html?highlight=boost_libraries):

```
foreach(boost_lib IN LISTS Boost_LIBRARIES)
    string(REGEX MATCH ".+/.*boost_([^-]+)-.+\.(lib|a)" boost_lib_name ${boost_lib})
    set(boost_lib_name ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})
    set(boost_target Boost::${boost_lib_name})
    if(TARGET ${boost_target})
        message(STATUS "Boost target found: " ${boost_target})
        # Process ${boost_target} according to your needs...
    endif(TARGET ${boost_target})
endforeach(boost_lib)
```

Note 1:
I tried these tips with CMake ver. 3.12.2 and boost 1.68.0. I tested the code in Windows only. Since different boost build variants can create the same library with different file names in boost/lib, this loop can find the same library more times.
Note 2:
This whole thing is weird a little bit, since you get back the list you just passed to `find_package`, so other simpler approaches can be better, like storing the initial list in a variable...